# I can't enter text via the command line, is it possible to do this?

Tags: autocad

When you try to automatically enter the desired content (and there will be a lot of such objects with text content and I would prefer to avoid entering all the necessary data manually), the input field moves from the console to the area highlighted with a red rectangle, which makes it impossible to automatically create signatures.
The question is, is it possible to make the input field of the desired content always remain on the command line?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdpHI.png)

I tried to find the question on the Internet by entering the corresponding queries in Russian, nothing gave results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that by "automatically" you mean copying and pasting from some editor to the AutoCAD command prompt.

I will never work that way, you must use a programming language and I think the easiest thing is to use AutoLISP.

Try copying and pasting this:

```
(command "_mtext" "36,0" "42,0" "your text here" "")
```

and note the empty string at the end "" that finalises the MTEXT command.